# Limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\exp(x)}{\exp(s\log(\cosh(\frac{x}{s})))}$ for $s > 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to determine the limit of the following function as one step of a longer argument and found out by using WolframAlpha and other programs that 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\exp(x)}{\exp(s\log(\cosh(\frac{x}{s})))} = 2^s$$
for $s > 0$. However, I'm not capable of proving it since attempts like applying L'Hopital are not giving me any easier results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a logarithm of the expression and replace $x=s \log(2/y)$, you end up with
$$
3 \, s \log\left(2\right) - s \log\left(y^{2} + 4\right) \to s \log(2)
$$
as $y \to 0$.

Comment: A nice approach by attacking $x-s\log(\cosh(\frac{x}{s}))$ directly. By the way, the substitution $x = s\log(1/y)$ would be sufficient as well since the result is $s\log(2)-s\log(1+y^2)$ then and with $y \to 0$, it yields the same result.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\exp(x)}{\exp(s\log(\cosh(\frac{x}{s})))} = \lim_{x \to \infty} e^x \cosh^{-s}\frac{x}{s} = \lim_{x \to \infty} e^x(e^\frac{-x}{s}+e^\frac{x}{s})^{-s}\cdot2^s = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2^se^x}{(e^{\frac{-x}{s}}+e^{\frac{x}{s}})^{s}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2^se^x}{(e^{\frac{x}{s}})^s} = 2^{s}  $

Comment: I understand the last three steps but would you mind elaborating why the identity $\exp(s\log(\cosh(\frac{x}{s}))) = \cosh^s(\frac{x}{s})$ holds?

Comment: $a^{bc}=(a^b)^{c}, a^{\log_{a}}(b)=b$

Comment: Absolutely correct. I guess I've kind of forgotten the basic power laws. Great solution.

Answer (score 1):

let's simplify the denominator

$\exp(s\ln \cosh \frac xs)\\
\cosh^s \frac xs\\
\left(\frac {e^{\frac xs} + e^{-\frac xs}}{2}\right)^s\\
\frac {e^{x} + se^{\frac {s-2}{s}x} + \cdots + {s\choose k} e^{\frac {s-2k}{s}x} + \cdots}{2^s}$

The series is a little messy.  What is relevant is that every term is an exponential that is less than the first term.

$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} \frac {e^x}{\frac {e^{x} + \cdots + {s\choose k} e^{\frac {s-2k}{s}x} + \cdots}{2^s}}\\
\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} \frac {2^se^x}{e^{x} + \cdots + {s\choose k} e^{\frac {s-2k}{s}x} + \cdots}$

Multiply top and bottom by $e^{-x}$

$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} \frac {2^s}{1 + \cdots + {s\choose k} e^{(\frac {s-2k}{s}-1)x} + \cdots}$

And as x goes to infinity every term in the tail in the denominator goes to 0.